# What are the origins of the words ぐう、ちょき、ぱあ in the context of じゃんけん？

Tags: words, etymology

Self explanatory. I've read that they stand for rock, paper and scissors, but I can't find any ultimate origin of why these terms are what they are. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are derived from the onomatopoeia used to describe the motions the hand makes when playing.

- グー comes from [ぐっと](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/62316/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%90%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8/), the way you clench your fist
- チョキ comes from [チョキン](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/145016/meaning/m0u/%E3%83%81%E3%83%A7%E3%82%AD%E3%83%B3/) (or [チョキチョキ](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%83%81%E3%83%A7%E3%82%AD%E3%83%81%E3%83%A7%E3%82%AD)), the sound scissors make when cutting
- パー comes from [ぱっと](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/177736/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%B1%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8/), the way you spread your hand

According to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%82%93%E3%81%91%E3%82%93#%E8%AA%9E%E6%BA%90):

> - ぐっと拳を握るからグー
> - チョキンと切るからチョキ
> - ぱっと手を広げるからパー